# Angular/Typescript Unit testing with datatables

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I am attempting to write a unit test for my angular controller(written in typescript). The controller users datatables. I need to inject DTOptionsBuilder into the controller in the test, but cannot figure out how to mock it. Here is my code so far.

```
module MyApp.Controllers {
export class MyController {
    dtOptions: any;

    static $inject = [
        "$scope"
    ];

    constructor(
        private $scope: IControllerScope,
        private dtOptionsBuilder: any
     ) {
        this.dtOptions = this.dtOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('bInfo', false)
            .withOption('bPaginate', false)
            .withOption('searching', false)
            .withOption('paging', false)
            .withOption('order', [0, 'desc']);

    }
}
}

describe("controller", () => {
var controller: MyApp.Controllers.MyController;
var dtOptionsBuilder: any;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.module($provide => {
    $provide.service('dtOptionsBuilder', function () {
        this.newOptions = jasmine.createSpy('newOptions').and.callFake(() => {
            return {};
        });
        this.withPaginationType = jasmine.createSpy('withPaginationType').and.callFake(() => {
            return null;
        });
        this.withDisplayLength = jasmine.createSpy('withDisplayLength').and.callFake(() => {
            return null;
        });
        this.withOption = jasmine.createSpy('withOption').and.callFake(() => {
            return {};
        });
    });
    return null;
}));



beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_,_dtOptionsBuilder_, _$rootScope_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    dtOptionsBuilder = _dtOptionsBuilder_;


    controller = new MyApp.Controllers.MyController($scope, dtOptionsBuilder);
}));

describe("on creation ->", () => {

    it("should initialize the controller", () => {
        expect('test1').toBe('test1');
    });
});
```

});

I get an error 
     "this.dtOptionsBuilder.newOptions(...).withPaginationType is not a function"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need to define dtOptionsBuilder so it can be injectable:

```
app.factory('dtOptionsBuilder', [function() {
  var dtOptionsBuilder = null; // initialize here...
  return dtOptionsBuilder;
}]);
```

Once you have done it you can inject it:

```
export class MyController {
    private dtOptions: any;

    static $inject = [
        "$scope",
        "dtOptionsBuilder" // you need to indicate that it needs to be injected
    ];

    constructor(
        private $scope: IControllerScope,
        dtOptionsBuilder: any // removed private
     ) {
        this.dtOptions = dtOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                                         .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                                         .withDisplayLength(10)
                                         .withOption('bInfo', false)
                                         .withOption('bPaginate', false)
                                         .withOption('searching', false)
                                         .withOption('paging', false)
                                         .withOption('order', [0, 'desc']);

    }
}
```